# Need help resizing images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a small script that resizes the images on a HTML page based on their native sizes. For example, if image A is greater than 35px wide, then resize that image to 35px wide, otherwise do nothing. However after a day of searching and many failed attempts i still have no idea where im going wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The images that i am resizing dont have ID's and i dont have the ability to add ID's to them. Below is my current script.

UPDATE: THIS IS MY CURRENT CODE

```
        <!-- DYNAMIC FORMAT SCRIPT -->
<script>
function dynamicFormat() {
 var allImg = document.querySelectorAll('img')
  allImg.forEach(function(img) {
    const widthStr = img.style.width;
    const widthNum = Number(widthStr.slice(0, widthStr.length - 2));
    if (widthNum >= 35) img.style.width = '35px';
    // other changes if desired
  });
} 
</script>
<!-- DYNAMIC FORMAT SCRIPT -->
```

Comment: Use a for loop and iterate over the `allImg` collection, you aren't doing anything to your elements yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be more reliable to retrieve width of images after they're fully loaded since the actual width can sometimes be different with the width set via `img.style.width`.

```
for(let img of document.querySelectorAll('img')) {
  img.onload = () => {
    let widthNum = img.width; // this should already be a number.
    if (widthNum >= 35) img.style.width = '35px';
  };
}
```